# Is it possible to transfer caches/artifacts between pipelines?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

In Gitlab, is it possible to transfer caches or artifacts between pipelines?
I am building a library in one pipeline and I want to build an application with the library in another pipeline.

Comment: Best solution is Artifactory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. There are a couple of options to achieve this:

---

## Using Job API and GitLab Premium

The first option is to use Job API to fetch artifacts. This method is available only if you have **GitLab Premium**. In this option, you use `CI_JOB_TOKEN` in Job API to fetch artifacts from another pipeline. Read more [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/README.html#when-a-pipeline-depends-on-the-artifacts-of-another-pipeline-premium).

Here is quick example of a job you would put in your *application* pipeline configuration:

```yaml
build_application:
  image: debian
  stage: build
  script:
  - apt update && apt install -y unzip
  - curl --location --output artifacts.zip "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=build&job_token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN"
  - unzip artifacts.zip
```

---

## Using S3

The second option is to use some third-party intermediate storage, for instance, AWS S3. To pass artifacts follow below example.

In your *library* pipeline configuration create the following job:

```yaml
variables:
  TARGET_PROJECT_TOKEN: [get token from Settings -> CI/CD -> Triggers]
  TARGET_PROJECT_ID: [get project id from project main page]

publish-artifact:
  image: "python:latest"
  stage: publish
  before_script:
    - pip install awscli
  script:
    - aws s3 cp output/artifact.zip s3://your-s3-bucket-name/artifact.zip.${CI_JOB_ID}
    - "curl -X POST -F token=${TARGET_PROJECT_TOKEN} -F ref=master -F variables[ARTIFACT_ID]=${CI_JOB_ID} https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${TARGET_PROJECT_ID}/trigger/pipeline"
```

Then in your *application* pipeline configuration retrieve the artifact from the s3 bucket:

```yaml
fetch-artifact-from-s3:
  image: "python:latest"
  stage: prepare
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - artifact/
  before_script:
    - pip install awscli
  script:
    - mkdir artifact
    - aws s3 cp s3://your-s3-bucket-name/artifact.zip.${ARTIFACT_ID} artifact/artifact.zip
  only:
    variables:
      - $ARTIFACT_ID
```

Once `fetch-artifact-from-s3` job is completed you will have your artifact available in `artifact/` directory. It can now be consumed in other jobs within *application* pipeline.

Comment: thanks sirdarpeace, a remote repository accessible by all gitrunner machines.